# Release a Singleton

Tags: xcode, core-data

In my app i have 2 seperate sections. The Login/Signup section, and the main app section. Depending on if a user is logged in, the app will attach the relevant section to the window, and away it goes.

My problem is that when the user selects to log out, the app deletes everything in coredata and user defaults, and switches back to displaying the signin/login section. The issue i'm having is how to release all of the objects created for the main app section. It makes use of a few singlestons etc, and after digging through instruments, i can see that not everything is released. I can doubly see this because a call that is made every 20 seconds in the main app section will cause a crash after the user logs out because it is trying to make a call to objects that were stored in the core data section, so i know that it's not being released properly.

Does anyone have any advice on this? Below are the 2 methods i have set up. I need kill to dealloc everything. thanks for your help.

```
+ (MessageTableDataHandler*)sharedInstance
{
    // 1
    static MessageTableDataHandler *_sharedInstance = nil;

    // 2
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;

    // 3
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _sharedInstance = [[MessageTableDataHandler alloc] init];
    });
    return _sharedInstance;
}

+ (MessageTableDataHandler*)kill{

    // 1
    static MessageTableDataHandler *_sharedInstance = nil;

    // 2
    static dispatch_once_t oncePredicate;

    // 3
    dispatch_once(&oncePredicate, ^{
        _sharedInstance = nil;
    });
    return _sharedInstance;
}
```

Comment: Don't really follow the question (too many words that aren't easy to follow), but you can provide a `releaseInstance` static-level method that simply sets the `static` instance to `nil`.  Won't that do it?

Comment: If the objects are reasonable things to have as singletons, deallocating them shouldn't be necessary.  Can you invalidate the 20-second timer until you need it again?